# How to find the slope exactly in between two slopes

Tags: geometry

I have two linear equations, i.e.
$y = m_1x + c_1$
and
$y = m_2x + c_2$.

I want to find the slope $m_3$, which is exactly in between $m_1$ and $m_2$, i.e. the angle between $m_1$ and $m_3$ is the same as the angle between $m_2$ and $m_3$.

Is there an easy way I can calculate $m_3$ from $m_1$ and $m_2$ themselves?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean *slope(s)*?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have fixed it.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a y1 somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, another typo fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The relation between a slope $m$ and the angle $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ it makes with the positive $x$-axis is $m=\tan\theta$. This is equivalent to $\theta=\arctan(m)$.

So
$$
\begin{align}
\theta_3
&=\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}\\
\arctan(m_3)
&=\frac{\arctan(m_1)+\arctan(m_2)}{2}\\
m_3
&=\tan\left(\frac{\arctan(m_1)+\arctan(m_2)}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{\tan\left(\arctan(m_1)+\arctan(m_2)\right)}{1+\sec\left(\arctan(m_1)+\arctan(m_2)\right)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1m_2}}{1+\frac{1}{\cos(\arctan(m_1))\cos(\arctan(m_2))-\sin(\arctan(m_1))\sin(\arctan(m_2))}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1m_2}}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m_1^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m_2^2}}-\frac{m_1}{\sqrt{1+m_1^2}}\frac{m_2}{\sqrt{1+m_2^2}}}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1m_2}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{(1+m_1^2)(1+m_2^2)}}{1-m_1m_2}}\\
&=\frac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1m_2+\sqrt{(1+m_1^2)(1+m_2^2)}}\\
\end{align}
$$

Note that although $m_3$ meets your criteria, so will the slope that is orthogonal to that slope. (There are *two* lines that are "exactly in between" $y=m_1x$ and $y=m_2x$. So in addition to the $m_3$ above, there is $m_4=-\frac{1}{m_3}$.

$$m_4=\frac{m_1m_2-1-\sqrt{(1+m_1^2)(1+m_2^2)}}{m_1+m_2}$$

Comment: Please, refrain from answering question where the OP shows no of its own work on the problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing the complete answer, indicating both possible results.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the equations
$$y_1 = m_1x$$
$$y_2 = m_2x$$
$$y_3 = m_3x$$
for $m_1 >m_2$ (at the end this assumption will not matter algebraically, but it helps with the geometric interpretation).

The angles formed by the linear equations with the x-axis will be $\arctan(m_1)$ and $\arctan(m_2)$ respectably. Our line should bisect the angle between $y_1$ and $y_2$. This angle is given by
$$\frac{\arctan(m_1)-\arctan(m_2)}{2}$$
Our angle must also be measured from the x-axis so we need to add back in $\arctan(m_2)$. Therefore we obtain
$$m_3=\tan\left({\frac{\arctan(m_1)-\arctan(m_2)}{2}+\arctan(m_2)}\right) = \tan\left({\frac{\arctan(m_1)+\arctan(m_2)}{2}}\right)$$
The rest is trigonometric simplification
$$m_3=\frac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1m_2 + \sqrt{(m_1^2+1)(m_2^2+1)}}$$

Comment: Please, refrain from answering question where the OP shows no of its own work on the problem.